# Clicking a button on Internet Explorer through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to click a button through Excel.

The focus is working. But the click does not.

```vb
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And objCollection(i).innerText = "Add items" Then
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        objElement.Focus
        objElement.Click
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

[image: Button Code]

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test...try to get it by id:

```
Set objElement = IE.document.getElementById("catalog.items.add")
objElement.Click
```

Comment: i have tried the above code. still not working and no error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test:

```
' Add references to the project:
' « Microsoft Internet Controls » and « Microsoft HTML Object Library »
Sub Test()
    Dim ie, button As Object
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("https://www.sampleforms.com/")
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
        
    Set ht = ie.document
    ie.document.querySelector("#searchVal").Value = "yaya"
    Set button = ie.document.querySelector(".search-btn")
    button.Click
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

So try with :

```
Set button = ie.document.querySelector("#catalog.items.add")
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i have tried the code and getting Type mismatch error at below code
Set button = ie.document.querySelector("#catalog.items.add")

Comment: getting error -- object variable or With block variable not set